# how to get initiator information for ajax request in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on a big and messy application in angularjs 1.3.13 
somewhere in the middle of application an API is called, unfortunately, i cant
find out what controller or service is calling that API, so I opened networking tab in chrome dev tools to find initiator, but initiator is always set to **angularjs**

is there any way or tools that I can find out what controller or service is making a call to API?

Comment: you can search for the url?

Comment: use the chrome `Debugger`

Comment: i have already using chrome debugger , and networking tab in debugger